# Looking for higher order Sobolev inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Hello,

On a compact (without boundary) Riemannian manifold (eg. some surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$), I'm looking for a result like
$$\lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^2}^2 \leq \epsilon\lVert u\rVert_{H^1}^2+\epsilon^{-1}\lVert u\rVert_{L^2}^2$$
for $u \in H^2,$ where $\epsilon$ is of my choosing.

Does this or something  similar hold (eg. instead, the inequality can have the LHS in $H^1$ norm and the $H^1$ norm on the RHS can be the $H^2$ norm.)

I saw something like this in Adams but this requires the domain to satisfy some unpleasant conditions. Thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you are looking for is interpolation inequalities. The question is more suitable for MSE.

Comment: @timur: but I find that most such questions on MSE go unanswered so thought this would be a better place. Also I don't think this question is "common knowledge" so to speak.

Comment: If $\|u\|_{H^1} = \|\nabla u\|_{L^2} + \|u\|_{L^2}$, I don't see how this could be true.

Comment: If you put the $H^2$ norm on the right hand side instead of the $H^1$ norm, this is Ehrling's lemma, which is well known.

Comment: But if you mean to use the $H^2$ norm on the RHS, then this is indeed an interpolation inequality. It indeed is probably in Adams for function on a domain in $R^n$, but this can be transferred to a manifold using co-ordinate charts and a partition of unity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on Ehrling's lemma. @Deane But Adams requires the domain to satisfy a cone condition, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Chris, any domain with smooth boundary satisfies the cone condition. You would cover the manifold by open sets that are diffeomorphic to a ball and apply the result in Adams to the function multiplied by the appropriate cutoff function restricted to one of the open sets and pulled back to the ball.

Comment: @Deane thank you so much. I better do some more learning!